# Separate "check all that apply" answers into columns, creating column for "others"

Tags: r, multiple-columns, google-forms, survey

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229769/how-to-separate-multiple-choice-phrases-google-forms-in-different-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) and @rjen's answer almost works, but I am having trouble adapting and understanding it well enough to make it work 100%.

I have some survey data relating to a "check all that apply" question. There are 13 predefined choices, all of them without commas, and the respondents could also write their own answers (below, respondent 1 wrote Discord, for example, and respondent 3 with "I like to share this with friends, family and other people). Therefore, my input data looks like this:

| Q1 |
| --- |
| Twitter, Facebook, Discord |
| Facebook, WhatsApp, Twitter |
| WhatsApp, Twitter, I like to share this with friends, family and other people |
| WhatsApp |

I'd like to have this output:

| Q1.1 | Q1.2 | (...)Q1.13 | Others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | Discord |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | I like to share this with friends, family and other people |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried to get there by the following code process:

```
Q1_names <- c("Blog ou site pessoal", "Facebook", "Messenger", "Instagram", "Reddit", "Signal", "Telegram", "TikTok", "Twitter", "WhatsApp", "Youtube", "Não me sinto seguro para me expressar em nenhum ambiente digital", "Nenhuma das anteriores")

amb_seg_correct1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Q1.1 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[1])),
           Q1.2 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[2])),
            Q1.3 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[3])),
            Q1.4 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[4])),
            Q1.5 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[5])),
            Q1.6 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[6])),
            Q1.7 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[7])),
            Q1.8 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[8])),
            Q1.9 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[9])),
           Q1.10 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[10])),
            Q1.11 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[11])),
            Q1.12 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[12])),
            Q1.13 = +(str_detect(Q1, Q1_names[13])),
            Others = str_remove_all(Q1, str_c(Q1_names, collapse = '|')),
            Others = if_else(str_sub(Others, 1, 12) == ', ',
                             str_sub(Others, 13),
                             Others),
            Others = if_else(Others == '', '0', Others))
```

It almost works, the only problem is that some of the options (the one's where the respondent has filled the max amount of options, aka 3) are coming back as ",,"

| Others |
| --- |
| Discord |
| ,, |
| I like to share this with friends, family and other people |
| 0 |

Any ideas of how to fix it? :)