# How do I separate nominal Mulitple Choice answers from one variable into single variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-choice

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109108/r-how-to-separate-multiple-choice-multiple-answers-questionnaire-data-that-goo). But the solution didn't work for me.

I asked tourists what kind of traveler types they are. It was a multiple-choice question with 6 different categories (Nature, Culture, Health, Active, Family, Other) and they were able to choose more than one type. In Google Sheets and Excel, the answers within one column are separated by commas. So I ended up with a variable that looks kind of like this:

| Traveller Type |
| --- |
| Family, Nature |
| Nature |
| Culture, Nature |
| Nature, Other |
| Culture |

How do I separate the traveller types into new variables of my big table in RStudio? It should look like this:

| Traveller Type | Family | Nature | Culture | Health | Active | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Family, Nature | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nature | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Culture, Nature | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nature, Other | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Culture, Active | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109108/r-how-to-separate-multiple-choice-multiple-answers-questionnaire-data-that-goo), but the function "mutate_at" didn't work, and also I didn't really understand how to insert my data.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(Traveller_Type =
                   c("Family, Nature",
                     "Nature",
                     "Culture, Nature",
                     "Nature, Other",
                     "Culture")) 

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number(), value = 1) |> 
  separate_rows(Traveller_Type) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Traveller_Type, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id Family Nature Culture Other
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      1      1       0     0
2     2      0      1       0     0
3     3      0      1       1     0
4     4      0      1       0     1
5     5      0      0       1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets you can try this

```
=sort(query(
  arrayformula(split(flatten( 
    arrayformula(trim(iferror(split(A2:A,",")))) &","& 
    transpose(arrayformula(substitute(query(transpose(B2:G),,9^9)," ",","))) ),",",true,false)),
  "select Col1,sum(Col"&textjoin("),sum(Col",,sequence(1,columns(B1:G1),2,1))&") 
    where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
    label "&textjoin("', ",,arrayformula("sum(Col"&Column(B1:G1)&") '"&B1:G1))&"' "))
```

[image]

Comment: And people say that Excel is easier to use than R.

Comment: what do you mean?